# Исключение повторов в MySQL

Tags: повторы, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `url` = 'wall1_1' LIMIT 15");
```

Как исключить повторные материалы по url например и оставить только 1?

Comment: Так а что мешает поставить LIMIT 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)
- [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- [SELECT FIRST()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp) или MIN(), MAX()...

Comment: Лучше было указать ссылки именно на MySQL:

[MySQL SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Там расписано и DISTINCT, и GROUP BY, и остальное